# ԥ character (Pe with descender) not working in soql where clause

Tags: apex, string

We have a scenario wherein we receive characters like ԄԪԥñ¿¡ from a API. We then query on a object which has a field value equal to the response. It works for most of the languages but for some characters like 'ԥ' query returns 0 rows even after maintaining the characters in respective field of object.

Please find below code :

```
String data = 'ԄԪԥñ¿¡';
List<Demo__c> demoLst = [SELECT resp__c FROM Demo__c WHERE resp__c = :data];
```

I have tried with different combinations and came to the conclusion that whenever 'ԥ' occurs in a string , query doesn't return the records.

Also , there are few more characters which i'am not able to paste in the question.
Any pointers?

Comment: this works fine for me: `insert new Account(Name = 'ԥabcdefghi');
Account[] accts = [SELECT id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'ԥabcdefghi'];` If character is valid UTF-8, it should work fine

Comment: Actually , same is not working for user object as well.What might be the issue?

Comment: @cropredy , I tried the code which you shared , it is not working in my org. Should i raise a case with salesforce?

Comment: Just to update on this question. This has been recognized as a issue in salesforce.

Comment: Please link to the Known Issue page once it has been created

Comment: Actually , we had raised a case for it and support is working on it.